# How do I properly configure conditional actions with user input in VBS with MsgBox?

Tags: windows, script, vbscript, runtime-error

Today I started trying to create my own custom Dialog boxes for Windows. I'm able to use a shortcut/wscript.exe to run a VBS file with the following: (please ignore the dialog. I know that Drive C: will not be wiped and I do not intend for that to happen. This is just practice before I make useful ones.)

```
Option Explicit
x=MsgBox("Proceeding will wipe the contents of your C: Drive. Proceed?", 1+48, "Format Drive C:")
```

My scripting works to this point, as shown below:
[image]

But when I click OK or Cancel at this point, then I get an error. In the past, clicking OK or Cancel just closed out of this completely, but now I get a run-time error, which I think is better than nothing at all. However, an error doesn't help me.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
x=MsgBox("Proceeding will wipe the contents of your C: Drive. Proceed?", 1+48, "Format Drive C:")
If x=1 Then
y=MsgBox("The contents of your C: Drive could not be successfully deleted.", 0+64, "Error Formatting Drive C: - System Error 5")
If x=2 Then
x=MsgBox("Not all of the contents of your C: Drive were successfully deleted. Please try again.", 0+64, "Error Formatting Drive C: - System Error 303")
```

If I add "instructions" for what should happen next, then I get an error when I open the file and I can't do anything at all

[image]

I have tried changing much of the code already. I have tried using dim, removing x, defining a variable, define subsequent msgboxs as variables, removing the parentheses, etc... I have only started writing my own VBS files today, but I have been doing batch scripting with .bat files for a long time. Even with the change of language, all my troubleshooting has led me nowhere, and I am almost positive that I have defined the variable correctly.

Can anyone tell me if I have done this right? I have tried numerous examples, but even [Microsoft's Official Webpage on VBS-MsgBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) is useless. I apologize in advance if I have made a stupid mistake somewhere, but I have already changed almost all of the code and I am still stuck.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated. I've already spent 4 hours trying to fix this one problem.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You need to declare your variables [VBScript Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry if it was off topic, but I checked the other Stack Exchange websites first and this website had a lot of VBS questions already

Comment: [so] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript 12848 [su] http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vbscript 233

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the links. At least now I know. I also tried using dim to define x, and it still didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try for this example :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Question
Title = "user input in VBS with MsgBox"
Question = MsgBox("Proceeding will wipe the contents of your C: Drive. Proceed ?",vbYesNo+vbQuestion, Title)
If Question = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "We proceed wipping your C:\ drive",vbExclamation,Title
    'Call your sub here to continue proceeding your script
Else
    MsgBox "Canceling the operation !",vbCritical,Title
    Wscript.Quit()
End If
```

For more informations about **[MsgBox Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1ft6yf3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)**